# With JPA Mapped Entities with one-to-many relationships, how can I add join criterias

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Given the situation: The database was created when Hibernate wasn't born yet, we talk true legacy here.
I have tables that never have deleted records, just setting an *active* flag on the row to mark an entry as currently in use. Queries usually look like:

```
SELECT * from A left join B on A.id = B.a_id and B.active = 1
```

With Entity A and B defined in Java, and A has a property

```
@OneToMany
private Set<B> b;
```

How do I annotate the property to add the criteria "and B.active=1"?

JPA-solution preferred, but if necessary we can use hibernate annotations too.

In a similar way we have cases where entries have an active date range, so we would have to add a criteria similar to

```
"and B.active_From >= now() and (B.active_to is null or B.active_to < now())"
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Framework with JPA?

Comment: Hibernate specific solution is the only option here. See the paragraph on `@Where` here: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-dynamic-mapping.  Hibernate also offers dynamic Filters however `@Where` seems to be what you are looking for. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Hibernate's `@Where` annotation to filter elements from an association. You can find an example and explanation in this [Hibernate Tip](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-filter-entities-mapped-association/).

Here's the short version of it:

You can set an SQL snippet as the value of the `clause` attribute of the `@Where` annotation. So, your mapping should look like this:

```
@OneToMany
@Where(clause = "active = 1")
private Set<B> b;
```

And you can use the same approach to exclude the ones that are not within the time range

```
@OneToMany
@Where(clause = "active_from >= now() and (active_to is null or active_to < now())")
private Set<B> b;
```